# libGDX freetypefont artifacts

Tags: java, android, libgdx, truetype, android-fonts

When creating a `BitmapFont` in libGDX from a .ttf file with `FreeTypeFontGenerator` the resulting font has serious artifacts around it:

[image]

Those artifacts only appear when using mipmapping, so does it have something to do with transparent pixels? I have tried adding padding to the resulting font, but it does not work. I also tried using linear filtering but the resulting font looks pixelated.

Code I am using to generate the fonts:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 300;
    parameter.color = Color.WHITE;
    parameter.characters = "0123456789";
    parameter.kerning = true;
    parameter.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear;
    parameter.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear;
    parameter.genMipMaps = true;

font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
```

Comment: what font do you use?

Comment: I don't see artifacts in your image, could you be more explicit?

Answer (score 1):

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new        
FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new    
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = 300;
parameter.color = Color.WHITE;
parameter.characters = "0123456789";
parameter.kerning = true;
```

try these settings

```
parameter.padTop = 5;
parameter.padLeft = 5;
parameter.padBottom = 5;
parameter.padRight = 5;

parameter.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
parameter.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
parameter.genMipMaps = false;

font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
```

Comment: It will work, but you disabled mipmapping - OP would like to have mipmapping enabled.

Comment: while mipmapping can help with performance and visual quality for textures that often appear at various sizes and distances, it's not always the best choice for all types of textures. For example, if your font glyphs always appear at the same size and are not scaled or rotated, you might not need mipmapping at all.